# Convert MKPolygon to UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath, mkpolygon

Is there a way to convert an `MKPolygon` to a `UIBezierPath`?  I have an `MKPolygon` that is using latitude and longitude coordinates to make up its points.  How would those latitude/longitude coordinates translate to coordinates on a `UIView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MKPolygon *myPolygon;

MKPolygonView *polygonView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:myPolygon];

UIBezierPath *myBezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:polygonView.path];
```

Comment: Thanks for that solution.  I implemented it and it is not drawing onto my UIView.  Is there anything else I need to add to the code above to get it to show up?  I have done some debugging and, as far as I know, the shape isn't empty.  Thanks for the help